# Proving the limit of a sequence which is obtained from another sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that lim $a_n$ = b where the sequence $a_n$ = ($b_1$ + $b_2$ + ... + $b_n$ ) / n and we know ($b_n$) is convergent and lim $b_n$ = b.
At first I thought to write lim $a_n$ = lim $b_1$/n + lim $b_2$/n + ... + lim $b_n$/n but couldn't figure out. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Since $(b_n)$ converges to $b$, there exists some $N$ such that $\vert b_n - b \vert < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Set $c:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N-1} \vert b_i - b \vert$. Then it follows from
$a_n-b= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(b_i-b)/n$ that $$\vert a_n - b \vert \leq c/n + \sum\limits_{i=N}^{n} \vert b_i -b \vert/n < c/n + \varepsilon(1-(N+1)/n).$$